# on prime numbers which are primitive roots of a prime

Tags: nt.number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Is there a prime number $q$ such that $p$ is a primitive root of $q$?

Comment: Have a look at Artin's conjecture.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a well-known open problem.

Comment: Ali asks if there is one (as opposed to infinitely many) such prime number $q$. This may be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gupta and R. Murta showed that there were infinitely many primes $p$ for which there are infinitely many $q$. Heath-Brown generalized this to show that there are at most two prime numbers $p$ for which there are not infinitely many $q$ that they are primitive roots modulo $q$.

Heath-Brown, D. R.(4-OXM)
Artin's conjecture for primitive roots. 
Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 37 (1986), no. 145, 27–38. 
11A07 (11N13 11N35)

Gupta, Rajiv(1-IASP); Murty, M. Ram(3-MGL)
A remark on Artin's conjecture. 
Invent. Math. 78 (1984), no. 1, 127–130. 
11A07